# How to return customize group by using underscore js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm calling and binding data using rest api and trying to manage group by functionality using underscore js. But I can't determine how could I do that.

Here is my returned data image:
[image]

I'm doing group by on int value that works fine but my expected output is group by 0-1,1-2,2-3 by `distance` value
suppose array is returning distance `0,0.224,0.50,1.22`
then output should be in two array `0: 0,0.224,0.50` and `1: 1.22`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should use

```
_.groupBy(data.response.data, function(d) { return Math.floor(d.distance); })
```

in this case you will get the output that you expect.
Check the demo:

```js
var array = [0,0.224,0.50,1.22]

console.log(_.groupBy(array, Math.floor));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply my code looks like below how can I modify that ?

var groupedData = _.groupBy(data.response.data, function (d) { return d.distance });
                console.log(groupedData);

Comment: @Nimeshkhatri I updated the answer, check it, please.